# Can I create a script with parameter that has [alias("db")] in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

If I define the following

```
[parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
[alias("db")]
[string]$database,
```

then I get an error

```
Parameter alias cannot be specified because an alias with the name 'db'
was defined multiple times for the command.
```

Which is true, since `db` is already an alias for the universal `-Debug` parameter.
Is it possible to define this alias without renaming the parameter?

Comment: This should work. Sounds like you have two (or more) parameters with the same alias.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry, you can't. `-Debug` is a common parameter, so `-Debug` and `-db` are switches that are available on pretty much everything including the functions you write yourself. As the error tells you, it's already defined.

Even if it were possible to go around undefining built-in aliases, that unexpectantly changes the meaning of a call like `test-db -db` for someone else who frequently uses `-db` instead of `-Debug`. They expect it to enable debugging output, not specify a different parameter.

Consider this function:

```
function test-db{
  param(
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$database)
  write-host 'database' $database
  write-debug 'debugging output'
}
```

Now call it with `test-db server`, `test-db -db server`, and `test-db server -db`. The first doesn't do `write-debug`, while the other 2 do, no matter where `-db` is. You also can't define a separate parameter `[string]$db` (or rename `$database` to `$db`) because Powershell will give you this error:

> Parameter 'db' cannot be specified because it conflicts with the parameter alias of the same name for parameter 'Debug'.

More info on this, per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/adding-aliases-wildcard-expansion-and-help-to-cmdlet-parameters?view=powershell-7.2) (updated since old link died):

> In addition to using the **System.Management.Automation.Aliasattribute** attribute, the Windows PowerShell runtime performs partial name matching, even if no aliases are specified. For example, if your cmdlet has a **FileName** parameter and that is the only parameter that starts with `F`, the user could enter `Filename`, `Filenam`, `File`, `Fi`, or `F` and still recognize the entry as the **FileName** parameter.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense (though is unfortunate).

Comment: For the exact reason that powershell will always make partial name matches, we write scripts that almost always use full parameter names. For more on using the built in parameters too, see the cmdletbinding() attribute . http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/07/07/weekend-scripter-cmdletbinding-attribute-simplifies-powershell-functions.aspx

Comment: Wow, how dumb to just assume that -DB should alias -debug -- because, who wouldn't want a -DB parameter to mean _database_?

Answer (score -2):

```
function test-db {
  param(
     [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
     [string]$database=[string]$db
  )
  $PSBoundParameters["database"]
}

PS> test-db -database srv
PS> test-db -db srv
```

Comment: Why does this work? Unless I miss something obvious, it looks like something not documented.

Comment: Add printing of `$db` and `$database` and you'll see that `$db` never gets assigned in this way. It's still shorthand for `-Debug`, so in `-db srv` and `srv -db`, `srv` is still the first positional parameter.

Comment: To put Joel's answer another way, "db" isn't getting set.  "database" is capturing the value due to positional binding (which is on by default for all parameters if you don't explicitly set it on one parameter).